# Community Builder - can't update profile

Tags: profile, community-builder

I am using the latest version of Community Builder in Joomla 3.8. I can not update an existing profile because it tells me the email address is already in use when I click on save. Can't clear the email field either because I get an invalid email address. I'm using the "edit profile" type in a menu and the same is true if I try as an administrator un CB's User Management

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you login with a different browser and dont 'remember me' (both Joomla and the browser)?

Comment: I found the problem. The users I was trying to update were imported directly into the Users table. If I add a user manually I can update this user without any problem.

Comment: Please would you mind adding this as a proper answer below and marking it as accepted once possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The users I was trying to update were imported directly into the Users table. If I add a user manually I can update this user without any problem.